# onMessageReceived called randomly

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've just released an update for an application and I've noticed something strange. In the app, push notifications are sent out to users when new news is available and this has been working fine ever since the first version, however, since the new version there have been instances where onMessageReceived is called but the bundle is null. Now what makes this strange is that firstly this only happens to two HTC users at roughly the same time and secondly no code has changed in the app regarding the push notifications.

When I initially looked into the issue I thought that the users may be receiving push notifications late and then for some reason the data was null, however, no push notifications have been sent out in the last few days yet this error is still occurring happening.

Are there any other circumstances why onMessageReceived would be getting called even if there are no remote push notification being sent out?

Any feedback would be fantastic!

Comment: Do you received any error message? can you provide us the logs?
Try to run in debug mode and check if the device is receiving it. You may try to test the gcm connection here: https://console.developers.google.com